# How to have zero downtime upgrades and low latency streaming GCP DataFlow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have set up a custom DataFlow job written in Python, that just copies an image (triggerd by a pubsub message) from one bucket to another and then sends a HTTP request.

It looks something like:

```
    messages = pipeline | 'On Pubsub Message' >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=config['pubsub_image_topic'])
    new_images = messages | 'Parse Pubsub Message' >> apache_beam.Map(parse_pubsub)
    valid_images = new_images | 'Attach Metadata' >> apache_beam.ParDo(AttachMetadata())
    collected_images = valid_images | 'Collect Image' >> apache_beam.Map(collect_image)
    copied_images = collected_images | 'Copy To Bucket' >> apache_beam.ParDo(CopyToBucketDoFun())
    data_bucket_images | 'Notify WebHook' >> apache_beam.ParDo(NotifyWebHookFn())
```

I run it in GCP DataFlow with arguments like:

```
python ./main.py \
  --job_name=$JOB_NAME \
  --streaming \
  --enable_streaming_engine \
  --runner="DataflowRunner" \
  --project=$GCP_PROJECT \
  --region=$REGION \
  --subnetwork=$SUBNETWORK \
  --staging_location=$STAGING_LOCATION \
  --no_use_public_ips \
  --setup_file ./setup.py \
  --service_account_email "${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" \
  --requirements_file "requirements.txt" \
  --pubsub_image_topic $PUBSUB_IMAGE_TOPIC \
  --update
```

This finds the old job with that name, and stops it, copies the state, and then starts this job and restores the state.  However, this causes 9 minutes of downtime while the old job is stopped and the old one is getting initialized.  Is there any way to keep the old job running until the new one is ready to process?

Also, I would like this pipeline to run with minimal latency.  However, this pipeline always has a minimum of 20 seconds "data freshness", even though all of the steps for a single message should take less than half a second.  Is there any way to tell DataFlow to prioritize latency, and to run all of the steps for a message as soon as possible? And to run them in parallel? It seems to run each step of the pipeline in batch.  Like it will read 8 messages, then it will parse all 8 messages, then it will collect all 8 images, and then copy 8 images, and then call the WebHook 8 times, and then repeat.

I feel like these features are obvious and necessary to have DataFlow run as a realtime streaming pipeline, but I can't find anything about it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is several ways to solve this

- You can accept the downtime. According to your SLA, you should be able to stop your service for a while, consume your error budget, and start your new pipeline. It's the normal life of any application. 100% uptime is never the target!
- You can run several pipeline in parallel. But your process must be idempotent. If not, that's not a suitable solution
- You can [update you current streaming pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline). There is some limitation, but if it's fine, it's your best option!

Comment: 1) I understand that, but thats just not acceptable

2) Doesn't work for us since we eventually need to calculate a stream of events that are sharded by id.  That means that there would still be downtime for that id

3) I do, see in my question I have ` --update`